# reload an specific div without refresh whole page

Tags: php, html

I want to reload just an specific div. I searched and read some similar questions too. What I made is below. What is wrong with my code that does not refresh the div ?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="reloadable">
            <?php include 'rand.php'; ?>
        </div>
        <button class="ref" onclick="refreshDiv();"> refresh </button>
        
        <script type="text/javacript">
            function refreshDiv()
            {
                $('#reloadable').load(location.href + ' #reloadable');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

$a= rand(0,10);
echo $a;

?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Because this seams to work

Comment: @ruleboy21 no I do not get any errors. Just refresh button does not refresh the div

Comment: Every time you do the refresh you're creating duplicate IDs, because you're nesting the new `reloadable` DIV inside the old one.

Comment: Why don't you load from `rand.php` instead of `loaction.href`?

Comment: @Barmar I insist on finding the wrong thing!

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean by 'load from ```rand.php``` ' ? How should I do that?

Comment: @SaeidEisakhani does both the PHP and the HTML lives in the same file?

Comment: @ruleboy21 no they are in separate files

Comment: Then you should do this  `$('#reloadable').load('name-of-the-file.php');` instead. Exactly what @Barmar is trying to tell you.

Comment: What do you mean they're different files? The code you showed is the PHP file that contains both HTML and PHP code.

Comment: The PHP code is `<?php include 'rand.php'; ?>`

Comment: @ruleboy21 I just replaced ``` $('#reloadable').load(location.href + ' #reloadable');``` with ```$('#reloadable').load('name-of-the-file.php'); ```  but did not refresh the div

Comment: Did you replaced `name-of-the-file` with `rand`?

Comment: Yes @ruleboy21 exactly

Comment: If all you want to do is generate random numbers, why don't you use javascript instead?

Comment: @ruleboy21 This is a simple example

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're returning an entire HTML document when you use `location.href` as the URL. The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/) warns:

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

Since you're returning the `<html>` element, this is being filtered out, so there's nothing to insert into `#reloadable`.

Instead, you could load directly from `rand.php`:

```
function refreshDiv()
{
    $('#reloadable').load('rand.php');
}
```

Comment: Sadly the result is same as above ! This does not refresh div (does not show new random number)

Comment: You may need to add a cache buster to the URL.

Comment: can you check this out? [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5w92yZ3gSRM)

Comment: Don't believe everything you see on the Internet.

Comment: I believe Barmar's answer should work. @SaeidEisakhani , did you include the jquery.js say at the top of your script ?

Comment: @KenLee no I did not include jquery.js. I just replaced ```$('#reloadable').load(location.href + ' #reloadable');``` with ```$('#reloadable').load('rand.php');``` . Where should I include jquery.js ?

Comment: @KenLee I added ```src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"``` to ```<script>``` tag but this did not work

Comment: Please see my answer (if it works, please mark Barmar's answer as correct. Thanks)

Comment: @KenLee If they didn't load jQUery they would be getting errors because of the undefined function`$`.

Answer (score 1):

With the pure respect to all friends that helped me specially Barmar and Ken lee, I can not accept Barmar's answer as correct answer. Because Barmar said `$('#reloadable').load(location.href + ' #reloadable');` can not run properly and mentioned some reasons. But I added

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

from Ken lee's answer and also added `onclick="javascript:refreshDiv()` to my original code attached to main question and it worked. So the following code is working

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<html>
    <body>

        <div id="reloadable"><?php include "rand.php"; ?></div>
        <button class="ref" onclick="javascript:refreshDiv();"> refresh </button>
        
        <script>
            function refreshDiv() {
            $('#reloadable').load(location.href + ' #reloadable');
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good to know that you solved the problem. Have a nice day and Happy Coding !